# Applescript, reading data from file into list to use with choose

Tags: file, list, applescript

I have a text file with three lines

```
Line one
Line two
Line three
```

And run the following bit of applescript on the file :

```
set dbs to {read file thePath using delimiter "
"}
--set dbs to {"Line one", "Line two", "Line three"}
choose from list dbs with prompt "choose a database"
```

Gives me an error :

```
error "Can’t make {\"Line one\", \"Line two\", \"Line three\"} into type string." 
number -1700 from {"Line one", "Line two", "Line three"} to string
```

So I take the comment tag (--) out of the second line to make dbs into exactly the same list it's complaining it can't convert, and the choose works. But I don't want to rewrite my code every time the contents of the file changes... Why can't it convert from one list when it can convert from the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set dbs to every paragraph of (read file thePath)

Comment: "every paragraph" gives me a blank line at the end but it is now clear to me the braces were being added to the response line and if I change them to normal brackets it works as I was expecting.